# Error: admin is not defined using HTTP request with Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I just configured my first Cloud Functions for Firebase and after deploying the `index.js` file and upload all the changes to my server. I'm trying to use one of my functions which is a simple HTTP request to create a field on a table in my Firebase Database:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
        // Grab the text parameter.
        const original = req.query.text;
        // Push it into the Realtime Database then send a response
        admin.database().ref('/messages').push({ original: original }).then(snapshot => {
            // Redirect with 303 SEE OTHER to the URL of the pushed object in the Firebase console.
            res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref);
        });
    });
```

But when I'm calling to my request on my browser I'm receiving an error on my Functions console which says `admin is not defined`:

[image]

What might be causing this error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to import the Admin SDK module just like you are importing the Cloud Functions SDK:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
```

Example code can be found [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/uppercase/functions/index.js#L24-L25). This is also covered in the ["get started" guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#import-the-required-modules-and-initialize-an-app).

Comment: You are right! I'm totally blind, I was doing the start guide example and I didnt saw that part. thx mate!